# How might re.findall be used on a string like "{asctime} _{|} {level} _{|} {name} __{>>} {message}"

Tags: python, regex

I have a simple string like this:

```py
s = "{asctime} _{|} {level} _{|} {name} __{>>} {message}"
```

I want to use regex to convert it to the following (preserving whitespace), likely using `re.findall`:

```py
[
"{asctime} _{|}",
" {level} _{|}",
" {name} __{>>}",
" {message}"
]
```

How might this be done?

Here's where I've got to:

```
re.findall(r'\{.\}', s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

p = re.compile(r'(\s?\{\w*\}[\s_]*(\{([|]*|[>]*)\})?)')
s = "{asctime} _{|} {level} _{|} {name} __{>>} {message}"

new_s = "\n".join([x[0] for x in re.findall(p, s)])
```

for testing purposes i use regex101.com

Comment: Ah, this looks awesome. Is there a way to generalise to there being *any* number of `|` characters or *any* number of `>` characters?

Comment: should work now with any number of `|` and `>` @BlandCorporation

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work

```
import re

s = "{asctime} _{|} {level} _{|} {name} __{>>} {message}"

re.split(r"\B(?= {)", s)
```

returns

```
['{asctime} _{|}', ' {level} _{|}', ' {name} __{>>}', ' {message}']
```

Comment: Hm, thanks, but when I try to run this I get a "split() requires a non-empty pattern match." error?

Comment: @BlandCorporation, interesting.  I just copy pasted it into a new Jupyter notebook and it ran fine.  Using Python 3.7.3

Answer (score 1):

You might also use a pattern without capturing groups:

```
{[^}]+}(?: (?:_{\|}|__{>>}))?
```

**Explanation**

- `{[^}]+}` Match `{`, 1+ times any char other than `{` and match `}`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:` Match a space and start non capture group for an alternation

    - `_{\|}` Match `_{|}`
    - `|` or
    - `__{>>}` Match `__{>>}`
  - `)` Close group
- `)?` Close group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jTsTqa/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gifG6E)

Example code

```
regex = r"{[^}]+}(?: (?:_{\|}|__{>>}))?"
s = "{asctime} _{|} {level} _{|} {name} __{>>} {message}"

print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Output

```
['{asctime} _{|}', '{level} _{|}', '{name} __{>>}', '{message}']
```

Answer (score 0):

not really a regex but this gets it done:

```
import re

s = "{asctime} _{|} {level} _{|} {name} __{>>} {message}"

ting = str(re.sub("} {", "}${", s).split("$"))
ting = re.sub(", ", ",\n", ting)
ting = re.sub("\[", "[\n", ting)
ting = re.sub("]", "\n]", ting)

print(ting)
# [
# '{asctime} _{|}',
# '{level} _{|}',
# '{name} __{>>}',
# '{message}'
# ]
```